# Drag and drop on image for touchscreen

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Well I found this tutorial on drag and drop:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

It is exactly what I want but it doesn't support touchscreen. What am I supposed to do to make it work for touchscreen too?

All I want to do is drag an image and drop it inside another image with support for all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var draggable = document.getElementById('draggable');
 draggable.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
   var touch = event.targetTouches[0];

   // Place element where the finger is
   draggable.style.left = touch.pageX-25 + 'px';
   draggable.style.top = touch.pageY-25 + 'px';
   event.preventDefault();
 }, false);
```

Here is a tutorial: http://mobiforge.com/design-development/touch-friendly-drag-and-drop

Please let me know if it works or if you need any more help with that :)

Edit: Here is [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw8ofs8t/1/) with a test I built a while before. I've updated it with comments so you should see what's going on there.
Maybe a JavaScript pro would want to hit me for this, but it's working for my purpose and I it seems to work.
I haven't tested it in older browsers though, since it's a personal project and I'm not going the "optimizing for IE way" there.

Comment: I didn't try it yet so I might be wrong but this only works for touch right? I need it to work for both and on the site you just sent I found kineticjs which works perfectly I just have to find out how I can detect when an image is dropped inside another image.

Comment: Sorry, I was gone for a while.I've updated my answer with a jsfiddle

Comment: Wow thanks that works like I want it to! But to be honest I found this in the meantime and it also works pretty well although I am still working on it. http://interactjs.io/

Comment: No problem, I've had fun playing with it ;)
And thanks for the link, that looks interesting and I'm going to play a little with that, too

Comment: Haha yea you are right it is kind of fun to play around with it :D I am making something where you have 3 boxes where you can drop something in (the draggable) and when you drop it it activates animations